# Update query with multiple table in where clause in MySql

Tags: mysql

I want to set the `term_taxonomy_id` = '4' in table `lp_term_relationships`
where `post_title`

Like '%Apple%'. Column `post_title` is in the table `lp_posts`. But it is giving me the syntax error. Any help ??

This is my Query:

```
Update `lp_term_relationships`     
set `lp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id` = '4'   
FROM `lp_term_relationships`, `lp_posts `  
WHERE  `lp_posts`.`post_title` Like '%Apple%';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to perform a proper join here. You have not mentioned the foreign key relation that links both of them...Add the foreign key relationship in the where clause as well..Your final query would be something like this:

```
update table1, table2 
set table1.col=1
where table1.id= table2.fkey_id
and table1.column2 like '%APPLE%'
```

you need to write the correct column names and relationship that links the tables.